# Problema con subquery

Tags: mysql, update

Tengo la siguiente sentencia que me sirve para actualizar los campos de una tabla detalle_dulce que recoje solo valores numericos

```
update producto
inner join detalle_dulce on detalle_dulce.idp = producto.idp
inner join existencia on producto.idp = existencia.idp 
inner join codigo_barras on detalle_dulce.idp = codigo_barras.idp
set detalle_dulce.categoria = (select idc from categoria where nombre = 'dulce'), detalle_dulce.subcategoria = (select idsub from subcategoria where nombre = 'chocolate'), detalle_dulce.proveedor = (select idpr from proveedor where proveedor = 'berny'), existencia.cantidad = existencia.cantidad + 30
where producto.idp = 1551;
```

el problema es que al momento de ejecutar me aparece el error

```
Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Comment: Significa que una de tus subqueries esta retornando mas de una fila.  Quizas tengas dos proveedores con el nombre `berny` o dos subcategorias `chocolate`

Comment: efectivamente tenia mas de una subcategoria con el mismo nombre, acabo de corregir los datos eliminando los duplicados y me funciono perfectamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que uno de tus subqueries, si lo ejecutas por separado es muy seguro que te devuelva mas de 1 registro, por lo que al usar el comparador "=" salta el error.

en caso de que, estés conciente que el subquery devuelve mas de 1 valor, utiliza "IN", para que así actualice todos los registros que estén dentro de ese conjunto de resultados.

```
set detalle_dulce.categoria IN (select idc from categoria where nombre = 'dulce')
```

Si no esperas mas de dos registros, utiliza un limitador para obtener uno solo (en sql server puedes utilizar Top(1), en mysql, no estoy seguro). Ej:

```
set detalle_dulce.categoria = (select top(1) idc from categoria where nombre = 'dulce')
```

Saludos.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta man, efectivamente 1 de mis subqueries devolvia mas de 2 registros

Comment: Un gusto haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

debes identificar cual es la subquery que te esta trayendo mas de un dato,
para esto en mysql yo haría lo siguiente :

```
 update producto
 inner join detalle_dulce on detalle_dulce.idp = producto.idp
 inner join existencia on producto.idp = existencia.idp 
 inner join codigo_barras on detalle_dulce.idp = codigo_barras.idp
 set detalle_dulce.categoria = (select idc from categoria where nombre = 
 'dulce' limit 1), detalle_dulce.subcategoria = (select idsub from subcategoria 
 where nombre = 'chocolate' limit 1), detalle_dulce.proveedor = (select idpr from 
 proveedor where proveedor = 'berny' limit 1), existencia.cantidad = 
 existencia.cantidad + 30
 where producto.idp = 1551;
```

si con esto te actualiza, que lo mas probable suceda, es porque una de las 3 subquery que le agregue "limit 1" te esta trayendo mas de 1 dato.

para identificar cual es, debes dejar solo 1 de las 3 query con "limit 1" cuando te pase el update, es porque esa query esta con problemas, y es en ella que debes trabajar.